# Can Cakephp read session data from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp

I have a Rails's application and i saved user's session in sessions table. It's run on domain example.com
 Now I'm developing a CakePHP's application run on subdomain cakephp.example.com. How can i reuse session from Rails's app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the Rails sessions are stored in the DB it should be easier. Unless the Rails session cookies are for *.example.com, your cakephp.example.com might not be able to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can although I'm not sure why you would want to. Assuming you are using Cookie Store the session is simply base64 encoded.

```
$rails_session = base64_decode($_COOKIE['_foobar_session']);
```

Obviously you need to replace the cookie name.  Additionally you won't be able to modify the rails session and use it in rails again because there are some security restrictions to tampering with it.  You can disable them but I wouldn't suggest doing that.

Another option is to store the session in the database in which case you can access it just like you would for any data.

EDIT: After rereading your question it seems like you would want to read the session in initially like I stated above and use that to create a new session in cakephp.